# automatic scatter plot generation of individual columns of a multicolumn dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe containing 1 column (x-axis=df_time) and a dataframe with multiple columns and each column would correspond to an individual y-axis that I want to plot against the df_time. When I manually  pick a column `df_column_01=df_column.iloc[:,0]` and plot it `plt.scatter(df_time,df_column_01)
plt.show` I get the desired plot. However, I would like to generate a for loop to do multiple plots in which the df_time is plotted agains the different columns. The columns are not indexed and the number of columns is variable depending on the dataset. I would like that each plot is also labeled diffently depending on the column used.

```
df_time=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
df_columns=[0.000281, 0.004689, 0.001860, 0.004920, 0.000898],[0.000200, 0.000681, 0.000365, 0.000994, 0.001803],[0.004689, 0.006368, 0.003613, 0.009146, 0.004439]...
```

when I try `for i in range(len(df_columns.columns)):
    col = df_columns.columns[i]
    plt.scatter(df_time,col)#scatter plot`
it does not work.

Comment: What is `df_raws`? Can you print `col` to see what it is? Is there an error message?

Comment: raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size") for some reason my col has a different size than my df_time. I have changed the df_raws to df_columns sorry about that

Comment: and if I look at len(col) = 6 but len(df_columns)= 90 which is the same lenght as my df_time

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate both the data frame and use the below code to get the required plot.

To concatenate:

```
dataframe = pd.concat([df_time, df_column], axis=1)
# df_time = data frame with one column
# df_column = data frame with multiple column
```

To get the desired plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(dataframe, y_vars="one_column", x_vars=dataframe.columns.values)
# one_column: column name in the data frame with one column (i.e. column of df_time)
```

Comment: thanks! the concatenation part worked well but the plotting part gives me an error ValueError: Either both or neither of `x` and `y` must be specified (but try passing to `data`, which is more flexible)

Comment: Read the error. You have to specify both y_vars and x_vars. The same code is giving me the plot you required on my side.

Comment: sns.scatterplot(dataframe, x_vars=dataframe[:,0], y_vars=dataframe.columns.values) shouldnt this work?

Comment: Well sorry. My bad. it should be sns.pairplot() instead of sns.scatterplot(). It will work now.